# delete file on ftp server from iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ftp, directory

i can't figure out how to delete a ftp file from inside an iphone app i'm creating.
i'm able to establish a connection, create directories, upload files, get a list of files - but i don't see any way to delete files (or empty directories) via ftp.
Does anyone have a code snippet for me? i couldn't find anything about this in Apples SimpleSampleFTP example code.

so far i tried using

```
Boolean CFURLDestroyResource(CFURLRef url, SInt32 *errorCode);
```

but it always returns FALSE and gives me error-code **-11** (*kCFURLUnknownSchemeError*).
The FTP connection needs authorization (username and password), but i don't know how to provide that when using CFURLDestroyResource?

Comment: did you ever successfully do this .. ? I am having same problem as you did..  How did you use
 Boolean CFURLDestroyResource(CFURLRef url, SInt32 *errorCode); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"ftp://user:password@ftpServer.com/fileToRemove"];
```